Drupal 10: hook_entity_insert and hook_entity_update Not Working for Paragraph Tagging
I am working on a Drupal 10 module that implements hook_entity_insert and hook_entity_update to auto-tag event-type paragraphs in a node when it’s created or updated. The hooks trigger logic that checks for paragraphs, compares tags with the node’s group, and adds any missing ones.
While the hooks are firing, the paragraphs aren’t getting updated. Logs sometimes show messages like:

“No paragraphs found”
“Node is not associated with a group”

…even though the data clearly exists. No errors are thrown—just… nothing happens.

Do I need to reload entities (like paragraphs or groups) inside these hooks to ensure the data is fresh?
Are there any quirks with hook_entity_insert or hook_entity_update that could cause this behavior?
Could the issue be in my custom helper functions for retrieving referenced entities or group data?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated! Below is the relevant code:
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_insert().
 */
function my_module_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface) {
    my_module_handle_event_paragraph_tagging($entity);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_update().
 */
function my_module_entity_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface) {
    my_module_handle_event_paragraph_tagging($entity);
  }
}

/**
 * Handles tagging for paragraphs of type 'event' in a given node.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $entity
 *   The node entity being saved. This node contains referenced paragraphs.
 */
function my_module_handle_event_paragraph_tagging(NodeInterface $entity) {
  if (!$entity->hasField('field_content_function')) {
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->warning('Node @id does not have field_content_function.', ['@id' => $entity->id()]);
    return;
  }

  $paragraphs = FieldHelper::getReferencedEntities($entity, 'field_content_function');
  if (empty($paragraphs)) {
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('No paragraphs found in field_content_function for node @id.', ['@id' => $entity->id()]);
    return;
  }

  $group = EntityHelper::getGroup($entity); 
  if (!$group) {
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->warning('Node @id is not associated with a group.', ['@id' => $entity->id()]);
    return;
  }

  $auto_main_tag_groups = FieldHelper::getReferencedEntities($group, 'field_auto_main_tagged_groups') ?? [];
  $auto_main_tag_group_ids = array_map(fn($g) => $g->id(), $auto_main_tag_groups);

  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    if ($paragraph->bundle() !== 'event') {
      continue;
    }

    $main_event_list_groups = FieldHelper::getReferencedEntities($paragraph, 'field_main_tagged_groups') ?? [];
    $main_event_list_group_ids = array_map(fn($g) => $g->id(), $main_event_list_groups);

    $groups_to_add = array_diff($auto_main_tag_group_ids, $main_event_list_group_ids);

    foreach ($groups_to_add as $group_id) {
      $paragraph->get('field_main_tagged_groups')->appendItem(['target_id' => $group_id]);
    }

    try {
      $paragraph->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('my_module')->error('Error saving paragraph @id: @message', [
        '@id' => $paragraph->id(),
        '@message' => $e->getMessage(),
      ]);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieves the group associated with a node.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node
 *   The node entity.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\group\Entity\Group|null
 *   The associated group entity, or NULL if no group is found.
 */
function my_module_get_group(NodeInterface $node) {
  $group = FieldHelper::getReferencedEntities($node, 'field_group');
  if (!empty($group)) {
    return reset($group);
  }

  if ($node->hasField('field_parent_node')) {
    $parent = FieldHelper::getReferencedEntities($node, 'field_parent_node');
    if (!empty($parent) && $parent[0] instanceof NodeInterface) {
      return my_module_get_group($parent[0]); 
    }
  }

  \Drupal::logger('my_module')->warning('No group found for node @id.', ['@id' => $node->id()]);
  return NULL;
}

Let me know if you’ve run into something similar or have ideas on what I might be missing. Thanks in advance! 

after adding your code have you cleared your cache, and can you debug your code inside the hooks.
